# Generate 1000 random samples of size 4, $Z_1, Z_2, Z_3, Z_4$ from N(0,1) distribution and calculate W=$Z_{1}^2+Z_{2}^2+Z_{3}^2+Z_{4}^2$

Tags: r, statistics

The end result I want to get is a Chi Squared distribution when you plot it and it makes sense since that is the conversion.

So I'm going to create an norm function like:

```
sample=rnorm(4000)
matrixsample=matrix(sample, nrow=1000, ncol=4)
x<-matrixsample^2
y<-colSums(x)
W<-sum(y)
```

with the dimensions 4000 due to size four and 1000 random samples.  However, I'm not sure if I need to loop or how to solve for W since you can't quite add the means and the variance of four normal distributions to get a new one, right?

Can I have some advice?

Comment: Why don't you just generate the chisquare distributions themselves `rchisq`?

Comment: (1) should probably be `rowSums`, not `colSums` (2) why are you taking the sum at the end?  What's the point of this exercise?  (3) if you want to know whether you get the same results as I do, why not try them both (resetting the random-number seed in between) and compare?

Comment: I'm taking the same because isn't that what W in the problem is?  Its the sum of the random samples, right?

Comment: Well, I don't understand the question very well.  But it would make more sense to me if the goal were to generate 1000 chi-squared deviates by summing the squared normal deviates four at a time.  If you sum them *all* you get a *single* chi-squared deviate with 4000 df.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
set.seed(101)
m <- matrix(rnorm(4000),ncol=4)
rowSums(m^2)
```

or:

```
rchisq(1000,df=4)
```

?

Comment: the latter clearly being preferred unless this is specifically an exercise in demonstrating the relationship between squared N(0,1)s and chi-squareds.